# DataGridView column variables "lost" when navigating tab control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a form with a `TabControl`. There are three tabs in the control and each one hosts a `DataGridView`. There are separate `DataView`s used for each grid, all generated off the same `DataTable` but with different filters applied.

The first two tabs work perfectly. The third tab, though, exhibits something unusual that I can't isolate.

I have 2 x `DataGridViewColumn` variables declared at form level :

```
Private IDColumn As DataGridViewColumn
Private NameColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

One is a reference to a `DataColumn` that already exists in the `DataView` (simply so I can quickly & easily refer to it by its index at other points in the code) The other is a "new" column in the grid that I add programmatically :

```
With dgvThirdTab
    IDColumn = .Columns("ID")
    NameColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.DisplayIndex = IDColumn.DisplayIndex + 1,
                                                        .Name = "FriendlyName",
                                                        .HeaderText = "Description",
                                                        .Width = 240}
    .Columns.Add(NameColumn)
End With
```

Assigning these variables works fine (I can inspect them in the debugger and see that they have all the correct attributes, indexes etc.) And they remain so throughout the code execution (runtime activities elsewhere in the form / other tabs)

However, as soon as I go to switch to this tab, both variables are suddenly "lost"?

```
Private Sub tbc_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbc.SelectedIndexChanged
    
End Sub
```

As soon as this sub is entered, both the `IDColumn` and `NameColumn` variables suddenly have indexes of 0 (and not the respective indexes of the columns in the `DataGridView` to which they were assigned) and so I can't work with them.

If I inspect the `DataGridView` at the same time, all of the relevant rows and columns are still there, including the two columns that are supposed to be referred to by these variables. But the variables are no longer pointing to the relevant columns. Everything looks fine apart from these two variables.

What's *really* strange is, I do the *exact same thing* with the *exact same columns* in *both* of the other `DataGridView`s (different variable names, obviously, to distinguish them, but the principle and syntax are identical) and neither of those grids / tabs have this problem. They work perfectly fine.

Also, if I reload the grids (I have a function which initialises the whole form, including the tabs and associated grids), the problem goes away and doesn't return. It's only the very first iteration where this weird "drop" occurs.

Now I know I can circumvent this problem by simply re-assigning the variables before proceeding :

```
If IDColumn.Index = 0 Then IDColumn = dgvThirdTab.Columns("ID")
If NameColumn.Index = 0 Then NameColumn = dgvThirdTab.Columns("FriendlyName")
```

But that defeats the purpose of having these variables in the first place (I should just be able to set them up front and refer to them as and when I need them) I'm stumped as to why these variables would lose their references like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Little bit of a guessing game when you pick out some code and give no real context, but my guess would be something around scope.  DataGridViewColumn and DataGridViewTextBoxColumn being reference types could even be the values you're assigning them going out of scope

Comment: Thanks @Hursey, yeah appreciate I'm limiting the extracts here but there's a lot of code in play and I didn't want to swamp the question with redundant code either. What bothers me is that none of the underlying data is changing, there are no "updates" to the grid, it is configured perfectly when the form loads. And then as soon as you go to actually look at it, it drops the references. The re-assignment at the bottom of the question works (and as I mentioned, the issue never arises again; it's only on the first attempt to view the tab/grid where this happens) I'd just love to understand why!

Comment: What _really_ bothers me is, it would be so handy to just add a data breakpoint to the variables and have the debugger stop as soon as the values change (and thus identify where exactly in the code this is happening, and by extension, why) But VS not giving me the option, even though I have VS2019 and building to .NET Core 3.1...

Comment: Yeah, you don't know how many times I've wanted to break on a variable change.  There were a number of requestions on the User Voice feedback when it was a thing.  Visual FoxPro could do it 20years ago...  Really though, your issue does sound like its variables falling out of scope